# error in android studio package android.veiw does not exist

Tags: android

1 it showing a error package android.veiw does not exist in my android studio

2 when i add a buuton and use onClick

```
package com.example.batman.buttoncheck;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.veiw.Veiw;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Button_MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_button__main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_button__main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void buttononClick(Veiw v){
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a typo mistake. i think this question should be closed/deleted.

Comment: Padmakar Pandey ji typo error is there  so nothing else seems to be there, better you can close it other wisely it will be negatively voted sequentially!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo.

Change

```
import android.veiw.Veiw
```

to

```
import android.view.View
```

And similarly

```
public void buttononClick(Veiw v)
```

to

```
public void buttononClick(View v)
```

Comment: @SMR 5 seconds answering, vote to close as typo, move on. Hope it helps.